# How do I remove a tooltip currently bound to a control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I'm currently adding a tooltip to a label like so:

```
ToolTip LabelToolTip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
LabelToolTip.SetToolTip(this.LocationLabel, text);
```

When I need to change this tooltip as the label's text changes, I try doing the same to add a new tooltip. Unfortunately, the old tooltip remains under the new one, which is really annoying. Is there a method to remove the old tooltip, or should I just make a new label when I want to change the text in a label?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a single instance of the `ToolTip` and use it whenever you like to show it using the `SetToolTip` method and use [`Hide`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.hide.aspx) method to hide it. Generally it is not necessary to create more than one `ToolTip` instance.

Comment: Ah, so I should just have a class instance variable holding a ToolTip object instead, and re-use it when it needs to be changed. Much thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The tooltip object works in multiple Controls at the same time. Create a single instance of the ToolTip and use it for adding and removing a ToolTip of any Control.

When adding you should use
[.SetToolTip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip(v=vs.110).aspx)(Control, "Message that will apear when hover")
When removing you just set it back to null with [.SetToolTip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip(v=vs.110).aspx)(Control, null).

Comment: If you are going to quote a source, you should attribute that source in your post.

Comment: IT's amazing this is not documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 4):

I modified Gavin Stevens's code to make it all static like so:

```
class ToolTipHelper
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ToolTip> tooltips = new Dictionary<string, ToolTip>();

    public static ToolTip GetControlToolTip(string controlName)
    {
        <same as above>
    }
}
```

Now you no longer have to instantiate a ToolTipHelper (hence it has no need for constructor), and thus you can now access this from any class like so:

```
ToolTip tt = ToolTipHelper.GetControlToolTip("button1");
tt.SetToolTip(button1, "This is my button1 tooltip");
```

Also useful with either version is to turn a ToolTip on and off, you can just set `tt.Active` true or false.

**edit**

Further improved on this:

```
class ToolTipHelper
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ToolTip> tooltips = new Dictionary<string, ToolTip>();
    public static ToolTip GetControlToolTip(string controlName)
    {
        <same as above still>
    }
    public static ToolTip GetControlToolTip(Control control)
    {
        return GetControlToolTip(control.Name);
    }
    public static void SetToolTip(Control control, string text)
    {
        ToolTip tt = GetControlToolTip(control);
        tt.SetToolTip(control, text);
    }
}
```

So now, setting a ToolTip from anywhere in the program is just one line:

```
ToolTipHelper.SetToolTip(button1, "This is my button1 tooltip");
```

If you don't need access to the old functions, you could combine them and/or make them private, so the `SetToolTip()` is the only one you'd ever use.

Comment: I supposed Gavin Stevens deserves credit, but I love the static solution.  Without getting into too much detail, I had a very complicated form with 100s of controls which were having tooltips assigned to them on every form submission and so you could never kill the old ones.  This solution saved me from considerable headache.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ToolTipHelper
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ToolTip> tooltips;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ToolTipHelper()
    {
        this.tooltips = new Dictionary<string, ToolTip>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Key a tooltip by its control name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controlName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ToolTip GetControlToolTip(string controlName)
    {
        if (tooltips.ContainsKey(controlName))
        {
            return tooltips[controlName];
        }
        else
        {
            ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
            tooltips.Add(controlName, tt);
            return tt;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var tt = toolTips.GetControlToolTip("button1");
tt.SetToolTip(button1, "This is my button1 tooltip");
tt = toolTips.GetControlToolTip("button2");
tt.SetToolTip(button2, "This is my button2 tooltip");
```

Answer (score 2):

To simply remove the tooltip from the control, you could modify the class like this:

```
public static void SetToolTip( Control control, string text )
    {
        if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( text ) )
        {
            if ( tooltips.ContainsKey(control.Name ) )
            {
                GetControlToolTip( control ).RemoveAll();
                tooltips.Remove( control.Name );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ToolTip tt = GetControlToolTip( control );
            tt.SetToolTip( control, text );
        }
    }
```

and use this command:

```
ToolTipHelper.SetToolTip( control, "" )
```

Comment: What exactly is this `tooltips` variable? It is not standard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem . I added a tooTip component In Design form and used it. I define a text like " " in Misc section in property window of the control I wanted to have tooltip text. After that , every time I changed the test of tooltip for my component it does not appear the previous test assigned and worked well .

In the form  code:

```
public ToolTip toolTip1;
```

(please note that when adding a toolTip to a form,  code generator creates the above line , I changed its modifier to public since It was needed , but if you dont require it , do not change it)

In program to change the tooltip text of control :

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(myControl, "The text I want to appear");
```