# ASP.NET tooltip doesn't unset with empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a TextBox element, which has the Tooltip set in the HTML to some text (using the 'title' attribute). As a result of an event, I want to remove this tooltip from the TextBox from my server-code.

To do this, I tried to unset the ASP.NET ToolTip property, e.g.

```
myTextBox.ToolTip = ""; 
//or
myTextBox.ToolTip = String.Empty;
//or
myTextBox.ToolTip = null;
```

However, when the postback is finished, I find that the text on the tooltip remains as it was, so it wasn't emptied as I thought it would be.

Curiously, I found I was able to change the value of the tooltip though. If for example, I just entered a blank space, e.g.

```
myTextBox.ToolTip = " ";
```

Then upon the postback event completing, the tooltip shows up on hovering over the text box, but it's blank. This is still a problem though as I don't want an empty tooltip floating around while the user tries to enter text into the box.

How do I get rid of the tooltip using C# ASP.NET server code? Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: hope this will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186105/c-sharp-remove-tooltip-only-supplying-in-which-control-is-the-tooltip

Comment: @ART2006 the above question relates to a Windows Forms (desktop) application. My question is for a Windows ASP.NET Web Forms (web) application. The API's are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the 'title' attribute, like so:

```
myTextBox.Attributes.Remove("title");
```