# ToolTip respond to mouse movement on PictureBox

Tags: c#, tooltip, picturebox, flicker, mousemove

I'm trying to make a ToolTip with text that changes depending on what you're hovering over on a PictureBox.  My code is something like:  (simplified to avoid confusion)

```
private ToolTip tt;

private void Picture_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    string rollText = 
        <code to determine what text should display based on mouse coordinates>

    tt.SetToolTip(Picture, rollText);
}
```

This works, but the problem with this is it makes the ToolTip flicker constantly when you hover over the picture, so I modified like so to prevent it from redrawing when not necessary:

```
private string oldRollText = "";
private ToolTip tt;

private void Picture_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    string rollText = 
        <code to determine what text should display based on mouse coordinates>

    if (rollText != oldRollText)
    {
        oldRollText = rollText;
        tt.SetToolTip(Picture, rollText);
    }
}
```

But now it only displays for a fraction of a second and disappears when you first roll over it, and never again until you roll out and roll in again.  I've tried setting `ShowAlways = true`, all three of the `Delay` numbers to 0, `Active = true`, `UseFading = false`, `UseAnimation = false`, in case it was replaying the first frame of the animation over and over or something like that.  No dice.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you even need the oldRolltext variable?  Can't you just access the current text of the tooltip for comparison?  Also it might help to see a shortened example of how you are setting rolltext.

Comment: Tried that, using `tt.GetToolTip(Picture)`, same result.  Not sure how the code to set the rollText will help, it's a bit long, involving several classes, and not really related.  I'll just say, it figures out where the mouse is and what's under those coords, and populates accordingly.  The ToolTip is not touched and no changes are made to anything in that block.  Might help to see how I'm actually handling the ToolTip itself though.  I posted the code I'm using here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165540/how-do-i-remove-a-tooltip-currently-bound-to-a-control/10465827#10465827]

Answer (score 0):

use MouseEnter think is better way.

```
private ToolTip tt= new ToolTip();

string rollText;
int mouseX;
int mouseY; 
private void Picture_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    //tt.SetToolTip(Picture, rollText);//option 1
    tt.Show();//option 2
}

private void Picture_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{   
    mouseX=e.X;
    mouseY=e.Y;
    string rollText = ("Mouse position is:  X:"+mouseX+" Y:"+mouseY);
   tt.SetToolTip(Picture, rollText);//option 2

}
```

also use MouseLeave to remove tooltip.

```
private void Picture_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {   

       tt.Hide();

    }
```

i've putted 2 option to try ourself for removing flickering.

Comment: `tt.Show();` and `tt.Hide();` don't take 0 args.  I tried using `tt.Show("", this);` and `tt.Hide(this);` respectively, but it doesn't make a difference - still flickers.  Doing the `SetToolTip` in the `MouseEnter` isn't going to do it, because the text needs to change depending on your mouse position, and that would only call once on enter and never change.

Comment: i think u have to set Variable ShowAlways to true.

Comment: Did that.  I even already said that I did that in the first post.  Didn't make a difference.