# how to disable System's caps-lock notification on textbox password field

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, tooltip

In Winforms `Textbox`, I have defined new `ToolTip` and configured it. I have set the `PasswordChar` to '*'. However, when caps lock is on, two `tooltip` is shown. One of them is mine the other one  is system's default `tooltip` notification. I only want to show my `tooltip`. I want to disable system's `tooltip`. How can I disable it?

Comment: try if this may give you a hint.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165540/how-do-i-remove-a-tooltip-currently-bound-to-a-control

Answer (score 1):

One way is to derive your own textbox control from the existing one and handle the EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP message.  Then just drag this control onto your form instead of the regular textbox control.

```
public partial class PasswordTextBox : TextBox
{
    private const int EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP = 0x1503;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP)
        {
            m.Result = (IntPtr)0;
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    public PasswordTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```