# How to disable system's caps-lock notification on Textbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox, tooltip

In Winforms Textbox, I have defined new ToolTip and configured it. However, when caps lock is on, two tooltips are shown. One of them is mine the other one is system's default tooltip notification. I only want to show my tooltip. I want to disable system's tooltip. How can I disable it ?

Comment: Is that system's caps-lock appear on password textbox?

Comment: Yes. (i'm in VB.NET) I've read that but it's in C# or C++ (i don't know) and i don't understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677123/how-to-disable-systems-caps-lock-notification-on-textbox-password-field

Comment: And it's not really a tooltip, it's a picturebox who display an image of special tooltip (i'm french so excuse me if it's not undestandable...)

Comment: Can you please provide us with some code?

Comment: @Hoh There's not any code. I'd like to show only my picturebox with a tooltip. I want to disable the system tooltip...

Comment: Can you at least make a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer [here](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/820658-caps-lock-warning-password-control), and have translated the code to VB.NET:

```
Public Class CustomMaskedTextBox
    Inherits MaskedTextBox

    Private m_DisableBalloonTips As Boolean
    Public Property DisableBalloonTips() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_DisableBalloonTips
        End Get
        Set
            m_DisableBalloonTips = Value
        End Set
    End Property


    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Private Const EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP As Integer = &H1503
        If m.Msg = EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP AndAlso DisableBalloonTips Then
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero
            Return
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm testing this code but can u help me cause there is an error : Impossible to convert an Integer in System.IntPtr
On line 16 (--> `m.Result = DirectCast(0, IntPtr)` )

Comment: Edit : I've tested the code without this line and it works ! Thank you but is it important for the rest ??

Comment: @Drarig Yes, it will work without it. The trick is that you avoid calling the base class's `WndProc` when receiving the `EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP` message, which prevents the message from being handled. If you want to return a result of zero (which indicates that the message was successfully handled, which it was, you just didn't *do* anything), then you can either use `IntPtr.Zero` or `New IntPtr(0)`. `DirectCast` doesn't work for object types like `IntPtr`.