# Disable password TextBox Caps-Lock is On warning

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, tooltip, capslock

I am creating a login thing and I have this problem that every time I click on this "Show Password" Button and the <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> is activated, a Warning pops up and won't leave (at least I think it won't, which for the end-user would be even worse)

[image: Caps-Lock warning]

I would like to get rid of this warning completely.

Before redirecting my question to this question:
[How to disable system's caps-lock notification on Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460336/how-to-disable-systems-caps-lock-notification-on-textbox)

I have already tried that.

```
Private Sub ShowPassword_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ShowPassword.MouseDown
    If txt_Password.Text <> "" Then
        txt_Password.UseSystemPasswordChar = False

    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ShowPassword_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ShowPassword.MouseUp
    If txt_Password.Text <> "" Then
        txt_Password.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The warning should disappear.
Hope this question can help other people other than just me.
Edit: Thanks Jimi. :D

Comment: When you do this: `UseSystemPasswordChar = [Bool Value]`, you recreate the handle of the control. The baloon tooltip will be shown for the new control handle.

Comment: So is there a way to get rid of that balloon inside the if that re-enables UseSystemPasswordChar? @Jimi

Comment: Well, there are ways. I can show you one simple to implement.

Comment: @Jimi that would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
[TextBox].UseSystemPasswordChar = [Bool Value]
```

the handle of the control is recreated each time ([`.Net source code`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBox.cs,525))

The baloon tooltip will be shown for the new control handle, as soon as the `TextBox.Text` value changes: the tooltips will pile up.

A simple workaround - since disabling the warning may not be a good choice here - is to set the [PasswordChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar) property to `Char.MinValue` or `Nothing` in the `MouseDown` handler of your `Show Password` Button, then set it back to the previous value on `MouseUp`. This won't recreate the handle ([`.Net Source code`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBox.cs,382)) and the balloon tooltip can be disabled pressing the <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> key.

Set `UseSystemPasswordChar` to `False` in the Designer.
In `Form.Load` or `txt_Password.Enter`: `txt_Password.PasswordChar = ChrW(&H25CF)`

```
Private Sub ShowPassword_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ShowPassword.MouseDown
    txt_Password.PasswordChar = Char.MinValue
End Sub

Private Sub ShowPassword_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ShowPassword.MouseUp
    txt_Password.PasswordChar = ChrW(&H25CF)
End Sub
```

Comment: Now the "Show Password" button doesn't work: https://prnt.sc/ojul24
Either with or without the if.

Comment: Follow the description of the procedure. Disable `UseSystemPasswordChar` first.

Comment: UseSystemPasswordChar is already set to false in the designer but it still doesn't show the password when the button is clicked. But I noticed the change with the Balloon Tooltip.

Comment: You haven't implemented it correctly, then. Update your question with the code you have modified. Remember to set `txt_Password.PasswordChar = ChrW(&H25CF)` on `Form.Load` and see that your button is actually triggering the `MouseDown`, `MouseUp` events, referencing the right TextBox name.

Comment: I saw my error, it was simple stupidity, I had UseSystemPasswordChar set to true in the load event, I am sorry to take your time because of my error. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: No problem. These kind of things can always happen when you modify your existing code. What matters is that you got it to work :)